# Rails console, how to see object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

In Rails console when I do

```
u = User.where(id: 1)

"he find the user with id = 1, but then"

u.email
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<User::ActiveRecord
```

Why rails console is always looking for a method and not for an attribute? 
How can I see a specific attribute?

I am doing this because I have a method in application to find a coordinator by user_id, like this

```
user_id = current_user.id
coordinator = Coordinator.where(user_id: user_id)
course_id = coordinator.course_id
```

I get this error
[image: rails error]

Comment: `u = User.where(id: 1).first`

Comment: You want `User.find(1)`, not `User.where(id: 1)`, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object

Comment: `coordinator = Coordinator.find_by(user_id: user_id)`

Comment: Or `coordinator = Coordinator.find_by_user_id(user_id)`

Comment: Thank you all, coordinator = Coordinator.find(some_id) worked great!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`where` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, which is an array.  `email` is only going to exist on a single object.  Try `User.find()` instead.  Otherwise, try `User.where().first` to get a single object back.

EDIT:
as a commenter pointed out, you may prefer to use the `find_by()` method instead of `where` in this particular case.

Comment: Instead of `#where + #first` it  would be better to use `#find_by`.

Comment: @yzalavin agreed.  I'll update the answer to reflect your comment.